# meaning of "idiomatic"

Tags: terminology

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/idiomatic)

> idiomatic: containing or consisting of an idiom

I guess I understand the definition/explanation of it.

[In a post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/have-someone-do-something-vs-have-someone-doing-something.2740266/), Timberfall, an English learner asks the usage of "Have someone DO something VS. Have someone DOING something", an answer says

> Both structures are **idiomatic** ...

Is "Have someone DO something" an idiom? If not, does that answer imply that "idiomatic" could also mean something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if you look up a word in a dictionary but can't find a definition that clears your doubt or explains a usage, try a different one.

See [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/idiomatic) (formerly Oxford Online Dictionaries)'s definition of **idiomatic**:

> Using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker.
>   ‘he spoke fluent, idiomatic English’

Comment: Thank you. So, "Have someone DO something" is not an idiom but is idiomatic though, right?

Comment: @PutBere That's exactly right. It is an idiomatic phrase. We can also say a sentence, a usage, or some random thing a person says, etc. is idiomatic.